# Bad request when sending a long HTTP post request with Jersey

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jersey, tomcat7

I'm using Jersey to send HTTP POST requests like this:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> form = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
form.add("body", "Here there is my text");
ClientResponse response = resource.queryParams(form).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

When I put in body element, text that its length is **7999** or less - the response from the other side is ok

However, if I try with length of the text of more than **8000**  the response from the other side is:

> returned a response status of 400 Bad Request

I tried to submit the same call from CURL in command line, and it passes fine.

The response status is 400

Could it be something in Jersey/Tomcat configuration?

I tried to add to tomcat connector `maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"` but it didn't help

Comment: Curl call have passed fine because you probably didn't include all HTTP headers in your curl request. If you have done so you are likely to have received a 400 response too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change also the Jersey command to be:

```
ClientResponse response = resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

Instead of the way that you sent it with query params.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey sends the data in request header, so once header size exceeds then its send 400 Bad request for that

You can edit tomcat/conf/server.xml's HTTP/1.1 Connector entry, and add a maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" to increase from the default maximum of 8K or so, to 64K. I imagine that you could up this number as high as necessary, but 64K suffices for my needs at the moment and its working.

**Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...**