# Jersey/Grizzly POST fails for large URI

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, jersey, grizzly

Relevant: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063666/maximum-uri-length-in-grizzly-glassfish-and-tomcat) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653054/bad-request-when-sending-a-long-http-post-request-with-jersey)

I'm developing a POST webservice (jersey/grizzly, for research purposes only) which should be able to handle large URIs. But if a URI exceeds above 8000 characters I get a 400 Bad Request Exception with no further explanation. I debugged/tracked it down to the grizzly maxHttpHeaderSize attribute. I tried to set this attribute but failed. Here is how I start the server and the request:

```
GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, new PackagesResourceConfig("org.test"));

JSONObject s = new JSONObject(webResource.queryParams(queryParams).post(String.class));
```

Thank you for your help!
Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that GrizzlyServerFactory returns already started HttpServer, that's why you can not reconfigure it on the fly.
Here [1] I've created a copy of the GrizzlyServerFactory , which doesn't start HttpServer, so the code like:

```
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    httpServer.getListener("grizzly").setMaxHttpHeaderSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // don't forget to start the server explicitly
    httpServer.start();
```

Hope that will help.

[1] https://github.com/oleksiys/samples/blob/master/jersey-grizzly2-ext/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/grizzly2/ext/GrizzlyServerFactory.java

Comment: Awesome! Thank you alexey! But is there now way to do this without creating my own class? (Since this is not update-proof :()

Comment: hi Daniel, I understand you concern, but unfortunately I don't see other way for now. You can file Jersey issue and ask Jersey folks to extend standard GrizzlyServerFactory functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried with shorter URI? Probably Your server is unable to handle so long URI.

You can read more about it here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Why don't You put request data from URL to request body?

Comment: Sorry but this is not helpful. I'm not using a browser. And I can only call the webservice like jersey want's me to.

Comment: But it is still probable that Your server is unable to handle so long URI. Please try with shorter URI and give us a feedback.There are also guidance about servers (and maximum URI size) in link that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the grizzly http server without starting it now

```
public static HttpServer createHttpServer(
     final URI uri, 
     final ResourceConfig configuration, 
     final boolean start)
```

So basically you create it normally passing false as 3rd argument.

When you get the HttpServer object back you can `httpServer.getListener("grizzly").setMaxHttpHeaderSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`
As was said before and don't forget to start the server manually.