# Jersey test set max http header size

Tags: java, jersey

Does any body know how to set the max header size while using Grizzly2 and Jersey Test .

I'm currently using the following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and i have a simple Test class extending Jersey test like this :

```
public class JerseyTestInitializer extends JerseyTest {
@Override
public Application configure() {
    // Configuration stuff
    }

@Test
public void test() {

WebTarget webTarget = target(URL);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.header("test",SOME VALUE THAT IS MORE THAN 8K Characters);
SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(someEntity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

}

While performing the post i'm currently getting a HTTP status 400 with no other information about the bad request. If I use a header value with less than 8K characters , than it's working for me.

Please advice.

Thanks

Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Please check on this question about URI size (this is also a header).

[Jersey/Grizzly POST fails for large URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857746/jersey-grizzly-post-fails-for-large-uri)

Comment: Thanks Aleh, i was able to get my answer from this link.